# php - How do I prevent online videos to download by idm

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I have a video sharing site .

I'm going to do something that prevents online videos to download by idm .

I use the following code for download links stop working after play online but I do not know Why not streaming most videos ?

```
session_start();
$server= rawurlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SESSION['b'] = 'true' ;
if( $_SESSION['b'] != 'true' ){
sleep(50);
echo 'error';
exit;
}
if($_SESSION['a']==$server){
sleep(1);
header('Location: http://faman.ir/error');
exit;
}
$_SESSION['a']=$server;
```

Sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: you might want to clarify what an "idm" is

Comment: idm acronym is a program called Internet Download Manager. Which can download online videos.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, You can't stop someone from downloading your video. You could have some level of protection from casual users if you deliver your stream live, but there are tons of software which can capture the stream too.

If you want to protect your video, why dont you look into various DRM implementations ?

Hope this helps.